# Virtual Machine Software that supports graphic card?

Tags: graphics-card, virtual-machine, virtualization

Is there any virtual machine software that will use the host's graphic card as its own? Some of the games I want to play require some sort of video card and VMWare WorkStation 8 couldn't handle it. It uses its own graphic driver instead.

I don't want to trash my HDD with unnecessary leftover files after removing these games when I've finished them so that's why I've resorted to using VM.

I'm using Windows 7 Professional 64 Bit.

Comment: I've used VMware Player 4 to play Diablo 3 with no problems or unusually large performance issues. Workstation 8 should be based off the same code so I don't see why you wouldn't see similar performance using it. What games are you trying to play? And more importantly, what graphics card are you using?

Comment: VMWare Workstation 2012 preview got the better 3D performance I think. It's free too. You just have to register.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Server 2008 with SP1 and RemoteFX.
You need to run a virtual guest (Windows 7 for example), where you will access the RemoteFX features.

Then you can connect to the virtual machine via RDP and you can play games and such.